# Hide Values with React Component AutoForm

Tags: forms, reactjs

A nifty [AutoForm component](https://github.com/insin/react-auto-form) I would like to use in my project simplifies capturing form data, but with only my basic understanding of the component it seems to achieve this by exposing the values to the url.

[image: Issue with AutoForm Component]

I really like this components take on handling forms in React but not at the expense of using the url.  How can I continue to use this component wihtout this side effect?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: preventDefault

```
_onSubmit(e, data) {
    this.setState({lastOnSubmit: {data}})
    e.preventDefault()
},
```

This turns out to be quite an important step for more reasons that just data showing up in the url.